# If I run my .bat (which opens FF), I can see the window. From Task Scheduler, it opens the url in FF, but its not visible. How can i visibly open it?

Tags: batch-file, windows-task-scheduler, taskmanager

This is all the `opentheurl.bat` is.  If I run it, the FF window opens, on screen, and does the thing.
If i run it from Task Scheduler, it actually kills FF, and starts FF, with the url, but I cant see the window.  It's not on the alt-tab list or anything.  I can only see it in Task Manager Processes.

```
taskkill /F /IM firefox.exe
REM sleep 6 secs to give time to close.
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 6 > nul
start firefox https://www.blahblah.com/myscript/
```

I'd like it to actually open a window that I can see, what I am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check the account set in Task Scheduler to run the batch.

Comment: Please provide how the task is configured in Task Scheduler.  Did you know there is a command called `TIMEOUT`?

Comment: To really sleep for 6 seconds you need to use `ping 127.0.0.1 -n 7 > nul` (7 attempts with 6 intervals of a second each)…

Answer (score 0):

Only tasks that are set to Only Run When User Is Logged In are visible. Other settings Windows protects the interactive user from being messed with.